# How to detect windows hooks intercepting keypress events?

Tags: windows-10, hook

I was playing with some key logging software for an interview.  After a little work, I was able to run software (using user32.dll) that could easily track every keypress including passwords - which was rather scary.

So I am trying to write some software or find a tool  that will allow me to see what hooks are watching the keypress event so I can easily detect if a keyboard logger has been installed on my system (or any system I want to use.)

All my searches show me ways to add the hooks.  It's getting a list of existing hooks and the software that attached them that I care about.

I am using C# - VS 2019 on Windows 10.

Thanks!

Comment: There are numerous ways of writing software to intercept key presses, ranging from the use of Windows APIs that were made for that purpose to code injection into specific processes that you want to monitor, and there is neither a simple way of detecting all of them or one that is completely reliable. Some methods include using `IsDebuggerPresent()` to determine if an external process may be tempering with yours, as well as verifying if the PE tables haven't been tempered with, it's all very technical and complicated.

Comment: You may want to look into questions like https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2262/12835

Comment: I know how to trap the keypresses.  What I am looking for is how to see what code has attached/hooked into the keypress event so I can check for keyboard loggers, NOT write them.

Comment: Obviously the first step is to know how they work.